# How to create an array of class objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a function in java script of the following type:

```
function x(id)

{
this.id=id;
}

x.prototype.id= '';

x.prototype.getId= function()
{
return id;
};
```

Now i created an array which will hold many objects of function x

```
var tok=[];

tok.push(new x());

tok.push(new x());
```

When i try accessing the elements, tok[0].getId

My output is:

```
function()

{

return id;

}
```

How do i access the functions of the class like object?

Comment: Exactly like you wrote it. `tok[0].getId` is the function. If you want to *call* the function you have to put `()` after it: `tok[0].getId()`. Other than that, I don't know what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks I forgot to add the () !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `this` to your getId function.  (and add the () as @Felix Kling commented)

```
x.prototype.getId= function()
{
  return this.id;
};
```